# Is it possible to identify a kind of scorpion based on a photo of its dried body

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Somebody at my university have came back from a vacation trip and brought back a dried body of this small scorpion.

Can you identify it for me?

This is a very tiny (?) scorpion, if I may say so. I can't provide the exact measures right now, but I'd say that the whole body was 7-8 centimetres long. Maybe 10 cm with its tail straighten up.

[image]

[image]

Is is endangered of extinction? Is transporting it illegal? Can it be dangerous (when alive)? Lethal (I've heard that the smallest scorpions' bite are the most dangerous / more dangerous then much bigger counterparts' bits; but that might be some kind of urban legend).

Unfortunately, I don't know whose belongings is this, so I cannot ask for a location where this dead scorpion was found. It was simply lying in university's kitchen as... I don't know what. A trophy?

All I know is that it is 100% not a native species. I am from Poland, eastern Europe and we definitely have no scorpions here. Due to to too low temperatures and the climate being very unfriendly for that kind of animals.

Comment: Definitely not small at 8 cm - that's a large one. No expertise at all, but there are scorpions in Europe (Spain, Italy(?) Greece, even the UK (whether it is Europe or not aside)). Likely to be a common species (as that's usually what people find).

Comment: Spain, Italy and Greece are all much, much warmer than Poland so that would fit into my theory. United Kingdom is on the other hand pretty much in the same temperature zone and climate like Poland. So, it seems that I must revise my thoughts and... watch my steps! :) Thanks!